# How to mitigate risk of spoofing / Impersonating in OAuth Device flow ( device code flow ) in Azure AD?

Tags: authorization, active-directory, azure

I have developed `C#` application and hosted it as a `windows service` on a machine http://localhost:5000 . This application registered in `Azure Active Directory

Application is using the below details in-app configuration

```
"ClientId": "242429ea-xxxx-4ddb-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"Tenant": "67ss7s7s7s-4e27-beee-yyyyyyyyyyyy",
"Scope": "api://12121212-5600-xxxx-1111-123456789/IoTGateway",
```

Application receives a `Token` from AAD and which will be used by `User` for authenticating (**OAuth Device flow in Azure AD**, sometimes called **device code flow**)

**Question**

Currently, all the employees of the company registered in AD, and `frustrated employees` who copy the application configuration values can get access by `SPOOFIING` the application. This is a risk. How to mitigate this?

Note: Attacker can shut down this application and run his own spoofed application at the same port 5000.

[image]

Is it possible to create a `security group` and add only users who are supposed to have access to this application?

**Example**

| AD All Users |
| --- |
| User 1 |
| User 2 |
| User 3 |

| AD Sec Group 1 |
| --- |
| User 1 |
| User 2 |

So `user 3` even after having the `secret`, he shall reject the request by AAD. Is it possible?

Comment: Code is not running in Azure, it is running on stand alone devices with windows OS, Is it possible to have a "security group" assigned to the application registry object in AAD so that only users in that security group can access the application?

Comment: @JohnHanley I have added an example in question so that it is more clear.

Comment: The user is not presenting the same credentials.  Device code flow uses token first, then token is used to authenticate, during this step, AAD will throw login and MFA challenge. here credentials are different. Maybe I am not good at explaining the problem statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue Resolved**

We can create `security group` in AAD and add only required employees who shall have access to the `App1` and validate the token in `APIM` before sending to backend services.

[image]